# Средства работы с БД для Python 3.7

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

Переезжаем на микросервисы, в проекте большое количество различных технологий, база одна. Львиная доля всего этого работает в стеке Java + Jdbi, поэтому для микросервиса на python ORM с миграциями не подходит никак, да и любви к миграциям в команде нет. Подскажите, может кто знает достойные инструменты для работы с БД с максимальным контролем и без миграций.

Comment: Ну pyodbc возьмите или pymysql вместо ORM - будет полный контроль.

Answer (score 0):

Скачать connector python https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='',host='localhost',database='test')
                       #(test=таблица в котором хотите делать изменение),  
                       #обычно так user='root',password='')))
cursor=conn.cursor(buffered=True)

       *********ваш DATABASE код**********

conn.commit()
```